# TFS Version Controlling in CRM without Multiple Orgs

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am looking for some inputs to manage version controlling in CRM. Currently, we are using a single development Org and maintaining the CRM Solution in TFS using Solution Pacakger. We check-in the entire solution in TFS alongwith its extract (extracted via Solution Packager). By this, we can know what all changes went in between any two solutions by comparing the extract files.

The issue with this approach is that we don't have low-level tracking of **who made the specific customizations/configurations**. Understanding the constraints of CRM as a product, I think one possible solution to this problem would be to setup a parallel development process where individual developers would make changes to their respective Orgs and check-in the changes (after merging). By this approach, we can track the individual customizations done by developers since they would check-in each of their changes individually.

Is there any other approach by which we can achieve this without setting up multiple Orgs for each developer?

Comment: AFAIK the approach you describe is the best practice. IMHO it's not really worth the effort unless an army of customizers is involved.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The reason we have to think around this complex approach is because we have multiple teams/vendors working on the same solution making it difficult sometimes to track who messes up things.

Answer (score 1):

The solution package needs to be one consistent package. When assembling it from multiple sources keeping everything consistent will be a real challenge. At any time in the deployment cycle you will run the risk of delivering a solution that cannot be imported.

So I strongly doubt if the suggested approach would prove a practical one.

When you really need to track changes back to individual team members, you may consider the following:

- Every developer has his personal development environment where he applies his customizations.
- When ready he only transports the modified components to the shared crm organization.
- Having this done he immediately checks in his changes in TFS.

Of course all team members need to synchronize the customizations in the shared environment back to their personal ones. It requires the proper tooling to keep this practical and some disciplin as well, but I think it's doable.

Comment: Henk.. When you are saying "transports the components", do you mean transporting them via a patched solution?

Comment: @Ashish: No, it is more convenient to just create an unmanaged solution, add the components needed to it, export, import and delete it. I feel a patched solution does not add much value in this scenario.